# Dropdown on click open class not working on new page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have this navbar:

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  jQuery('.nav li.dropdown').hover(function() {
    jQuery(this).addClass('open');
  }, function() {
    jQuery(this).removeClass('open');
  });
});
```

```css
.dropdown-menu {
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 178px;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1000;
  display: none;
  float: left;
  min-width: 160px;
  padding: 5px 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.dropdown-menu li {
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-menu li.dropdown .dropdown-menu {
  top: 210px;
}

.dropdown-menu li.dropdown {
  background: url(http://decombh.org/img/nav_down.png) no-repeat bottom right !important;
  background-position: 5px 9px !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="menu-demenu-container">
  <ul id="menu-demenu" class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li id="menu-item-62" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-home current-menu-item page_item page-item-56 current_page_item menu-item-has-children menu-item-62 dropdown active"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/">HOME</a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li id="menu-item-1306" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1306"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/index.php/contact/">ADRESSE</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-1325" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1325"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/index.php/infos-zum-ritten/">INFOS</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-1326" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1326"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/index.php/gutscheine/">GUTSCHEINE</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-1327" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1327"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/index.php/waitere-annehmlichkeiten/">ANNEHMLICHKEITEN</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-1328" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1328"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/index.php/bankdaten/">BANKDATEN</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li id="menu-item-436" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-436 dropdown"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/index.php/camping/">CAMPING</a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li id="menu-item-977" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-977"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/index.php/paket/">PAKET</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-1169" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1169"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/index.php/kategorie-a/">KATEGORIE A</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-1181" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1181"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/index.php/kategorie-b/">KATEGORIE B</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-1180" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1180"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/index.php/kategorie-c/">KATEGORIE C</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-1023" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1023"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/index.php/hunde/">HUNDE</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-1278" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1278"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/index.php/platz/">PLATZ</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li id="menu-item-523" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-523 dropdown"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/index.php/baumg/">BAUM</a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li id="menu-item-1714" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1714"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/index.php/haus/">HAUS</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-1258" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1258"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/index.php/rund/">RUND</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-1277" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1277"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/index.php/gut/">GUT</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li id="menu-item-506" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-506 dropdown"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/index.php/alm/">ALM</a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li id="menu-item-1259" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1259"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/index.php/sorglos/">SORGLOS</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-568" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-568"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/index.php/alm1/">Alm1</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-1121" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1121"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/index.php/alm2/">Alm2</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-1135" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1135"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/index.php/alm3/">Alm3</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-1119" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1119"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/index.php/alm4/">Alm4</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-1120" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1120"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/index.php/alm5/">Alm5</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-1118" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1118"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/index.php/alm6/">Alm6</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-1276" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1276"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/index.php/wissen/">WISE</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li id="menu-item-502" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-502"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/index.php/kids-zone/">KIDS ZONE</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-503" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-503"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/index.php/spa-2/">SPA</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-505" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-505 dropdown"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/index.php/gastronomie/">GASTRONOMIE</a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li id="menu-item-718" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-718"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/index.php/pizza-2/">PIZZA</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-504" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-504"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/index.php/restaurant/">RESTAURANT</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li id="menu-item-45" class="pll-parent-menu-item menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current-menu-parent menu-item-has-children menu-item-45 dropdown">
      <a href="#pll_switcher"><img src="data:image/png;base64,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"
          title="Deutsch" alt="Deutsch"><span style="margin-left:0.3em;">Deutsch</span></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li class="lang-item lang-item-2 lang-item-en lang-item-first menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-45-en">
          <a href="http://localhost/wordpress/index.php/en/homeen/"><img src="data:image/png;base64,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"
              title="English" alt="English"><span style="margin-left:0.3em;">English</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="lang-item lang-item-5 lang-item-it menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-45-it">
          <a href="http://localhost/wordpress/index.php/it/homeit/"><img src="data:image/png;base64,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"
              title="Italiano" alt="Italiano"><span style="margin-left:0.3em;">Italiano</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="lang-item lang-item-9 lang-item-de current-lang menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current_page_item menu-item-home menu-item-45-de">
          <a href="http://localhost/wordpress/"><img src="data:image/png;base64,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"
              title="Deutsch" alt="Deutsch"><span style="margin-left:0.3em;">Deutsch</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="lang-item lang-item-13 lang-item-nl menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-45-nl">
          <a href="http://localhost/wordpress/index.php/nl/homenl/"><img src="data:image/png;base64,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"
              title="Nederlands" alt="Nederlands"><span style="margin-left:0.3em;">Nederlands</span></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

And I want to achieve this behavior, when you click on a navbar item, let's say CAMPING, I want to be redirected to the camping page:

```
<a href="http://localhost/wordpress/index.php/camping/">CAMPING</a>
```

and then persistently display (until you change to another navbar item) the dropdown corresponding to the CAMPING item when you are on the CAMPING page.
**I want to achieve a similar behavior like this navbar on this website example:** https://www.wickinn.com/

Because I'm working on WordPress I'm a bit restricted on the HTML structure because it's generated by a PHP walker class and I don't plan to change it too much. But I have a custom CSS and jQuery that I can work around, my example is now with hover, but in order to get to my desired workflow I tried something like this :

```
jQuery('.nav li.dropdown').click(function(e) {
    jQuery(this).addClass('open');
    e.stopPropagation();
}, function() {
    jQuery(this).removeClass('open');
});
```

But because I'm changing window location `href` when I'm clicking a nav item this won't take effect, any suggestions how I get to my desired behavior only by changing jQuery and CSS?

Comment: Have you deployed your code on any server? Because redirection works fine on above code snippet.

Comment: It does, but the dropdown won't be persistent there when you go to that page, check my desired behavoir at : https://www.wickinn.com/ . I want to achieve that.

Comment: There is no submenu in https://www.wickinn.com/, you just want your navigation to look n feel like https://www.wickinn.com/?

Comment: Yes, if you click the RESTAURANTS AND CAFES you will get the submenu down: THE POINTE RESTAURANT
WINE CELLAR
ON THE ROCKS BAR
DRIFTWOOD CAFÉ

Comment: And you will be redirected to the page also: RESTAURANTS AND CAFES

Comment: Now i get it. Have you deployed your code on any server and are you using wordpress?

Comment: I have wordpress on on my local LAMP server, so it should be the same as a random server.

Comment: Great! Do you want to show sub menu on parent button hover?

Comment: I want to show it on click, and be persistent there until you change to another nav item.

Comment: Exactly as wikin have it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove **below jQuery script** no longer required this.

```
jQuery('.nav li.dropdown').click(function(e) {
    jQuery(this).addClass('open');
    e.stopPropagation();
}, function() {
    jQuery(this).removeClass('open');
});
```

and add **below CSS** in the stylesheet.

```
.navbar-nav .current_page_item .dropdown-menu,
.navbar-nav .current-menu-ancestor .dropdown-menu {
  display: block;
}
```

```js
$('.pll-parent-menu-item').click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('open');
})
```

```css
.dropdown-menu {
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 178px;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1000;
  display: none;
  float: left;
  min-width: 160px;
  padding: 5px 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.dropdown-menu li {
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-menu li.dropdown .dropdown-menu {
  top: 210px;
}

.dropdown-menu li.dropdown {
  background: url(http://decombh.org/img/nav_down.png) no-repeat bottom right !important;
  background-position: 5px 9px !important;
}

.navbar-nav .current_page_item .dropdown-menu,
.navbar-nav .current-menu-ancestor .dropdown-menu {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="menu-demenu-container">
  <ul id="menu-demenu" class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li id="menu-item-62" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-home current-menu-item page_item page-item-56 current_page_item menu-item-has-children menu-item-62 dropdown active"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/">HOME</a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li id="menu-item-1306" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1306"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/index.php/contact/">ADRESSE</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-1325" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1325"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/index.php/infos-zum-ritten/">INFOS</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-1326" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1326"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/index.php/gutscheine/">GUTSCHEINE</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-1327" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1327"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/index.php/waitere-annehmlichkeiten/">ANNEHMLICHKEITEN</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-1328" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1328"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/index.php/bankdaten/">BANKDATEN</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li id="menu-item-436" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-436 dropdown"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/index.php/camping/">CAMPING</a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li id="menu-item-977" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-977"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/index.php/paket/">PAKET</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-1169" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1169"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/index.php/kategorie-a/">KATEGORIE A</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-1181" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1181"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/index.php/kategorie-b/">KATEGORIE B</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-1180" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1180"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/index.php/kategorie-c/">KATEGORIE C</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-1023" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1023"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/index.php/hunde/">HUNDE</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-1278" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1278"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/index.php/platz/">PLATZ</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li id="menu-item-523" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-523 dropdown"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/index.php/baumg/">BAUM</a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li id="menu-item-1714" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1714"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/index.php/haus/">HAUS</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-1258" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1258"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/index.php/rund/">RUND</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-1277" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1277"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/index.php/gut/">GUT</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li id="menu-item-506" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-506 dropdown"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/index.php/alm/">ALM</a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li id="menu-item-1259" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1259"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/index.php/sorglos/">SORGLOS</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-568" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-568"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/index.php/alm1/">Alm1</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-1121" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1121"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/index.php/alm2/">Alm2</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-1135" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1135"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/index.php/alm3/">Alm3</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-1119" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1119"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/index.php/alm4/">Alm4</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-1120" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1120"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/index.php/alm5/">Alm5</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-1118" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1118"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/index.php/alm6/">Alm6</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-1276" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1276"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/index.php/wissen/">WISE</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li id="menu-item-502" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-502"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/index.php/kids-zone/">KIDS ZONE</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-503" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-503"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/index.php/spa-2/">SPA</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-505" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-505 dropdown"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/index.php/gastronomie/">GASTRONOMIE</a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li id="menu-item-718" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-718"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/index.php/pizza-2/">PIZZA</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-504" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-504"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/index.php/restaurant/">RESTAURANT</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li id="menu-item-45" class="pll-parent-menu-item menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current-menu-parent menu-item-has-children menu-item-45 dropdown">
      <a href="#pll_switcher"><img src="data:image/png;base64,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"
          title="Deutsch" alt="Deutsch"><span style="margin-left:0.3em;">Deutsch</span></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li class="lang-item lang-item-2 lang-item-en lang-item-first menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-45-en">
          <a href="http://localhost/wordpress/index.php/en/homeen/"><img src="data:image/png;base64,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"
              title="English" alt="English"><span style="margin-left:0.3em;">English</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="lang-item lang-item-5 lang-item-it menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-45-it">
          <a href="http://localhost/wordpress/index.php/it/homeit/"><img src="data:image/png;base64,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"
              title="Italiano" alt="Italiano"><span style="margin-left:0.3em;">Italiano</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="lang-item lang-item-9 lang-item-de current-lang menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current_page_item menu-item-home menu-item-45-de">
          <a href="http://localhost/wordpress/"><img src="data:image/png;base64,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"
              title="Deutsch" alt="Deutsch"><span style="margin-left:0.3em;">Deutsch</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="lang-item lang-item-13 lang-item-nl menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-45-nl">
          <a href="http://localhost/wordpress/index.php/nl/homenl/"><img src="data:image/png;base64,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"
              title="Nederlands" alt="Nederlands"><span style="margin-left:0.3em;">Nederlands</span></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I hope it'll help you out. Thanks

Comment: That is really close for what I need, only on thing, when i'm switching on the dropdown pages, dropdown items will dissapear.

Comment: To be more exact, if I click on any dropdown item, the sub menu will dissapear.

Comment: I just update the **CSS** in the above code snippet, try this I hope it'll help you out. Thanks

Comment: Perfect, last question, only thing that I can see right now is when you go to the languages dropdown, it seem that drop-down won't show on click at all. Thank you so much!

Comment: I just add **CSS** for language dropdown, it'll visible when user hovers on it. Thanks

Comment: It's possible to be visible on click ? The exact same like other menu items dropdown?

Comment: I Just remove last CSS and jQuery for that. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For what I saw in your example, the only error I got was

```
Mixed Content: The page at '<URL>' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure resource '<URL>'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
```

if I manually set the href url to use https instead of http, it worked.

not sure if this is linked to the snippet settings tho, but I guess it's worth giving a shot.